# How to write the distribution of the (Euclidean) distance between two random points with arbitrary distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, metric-spaces, random-variables, change-of-variable

Let the random variable $ \hat{{\mathbf x}}_i $ be defined over a some D-dimensional space (I'm interested in D=2), with distribution $ f_i(\mathbf x) $. What is the distribution of Euclidean distance between samples from $i$ and $j$?

**My attempt:**

Let us consider the squared Euclidean distance in 2D, defined as:

$$
d (\mathbf u, \mathbf v) = (u_x - v_x)^2 + (u_y - v_y)^2
$$

The PDF $f_d$  of the random variable $\hat d$ which is the squared Euclidean distance between the mutually-independent random variables $\hat{\mathbf u} = \hat{\mathbf x}_i$  and  $\hat{\mathbf v} = \hat{\mathbf x}_j$, with PDFs $f_{\hat u}(u_x, u_y)$ and $f_{\hat v}(v_x, v_y)$, respectively, can be found using change of variables.
Let us define the auxiliary variables $a = (u_x - v_x)^2 - (u_y - v_y)^2, b= u_x, c=u_y$. We can then write $ u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$ as:

\begin{align}
u_x &= b \\
u_y &= c \\
v_x &= b - \sqrt{\frac{d+a}{2}} \\
v_y &= c - \sqrt{\frac{d-a}{2}}
\end{align}

The Jacobian of the change of variables is:

\begin{align}
\mathbf J = \begin{vmatrix}0 & 0 & k_1 & k_2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & k_1 & -k_2\end{vmatrix} = 2k_1 k_2 = \frac14 \frac1{\sqrt{d^2 - a^2}}
\end{align}
with $k_1 = -\left(2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{d+a}\right)^{-1}$ and $k_2 = \left(2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{d-a}\right)^{-1}$.

The PDF of the joint distribution $g_{a,b,c,d}$ can be found as:

$$
g_{\hat a,\hat b,\hat c,\hat d}(a,b,c,d) = \frac14 \frac1{\sqrt{d^2 - a^2}} f_{\hat u}(b, c) f_{\hat v}\left(b - \sqrt{\frac{d+a}{2}}, c - \sqrt{\frac{d-a}{2}}\right)
$$

and, in principle, it is possible to calculate the PDF $f_{\hat d} (d)$ as the marginal distribution of $g$ by integrating over the entire domain of $a, b, c$:

$$
f_{\hat d}(d) = \int \int \int g_{\hat a,\hat b,\hat c,\hat d}(a,b,c,d) \mathrm d a \mathrm d b \mathrm d c
$$

**Is there an alternative, better, way of defining $f_{\hat d}(d)$ ?**